# How to perform JObject insert into MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

i want to perform crud operations on MongoDB using below `JObject(Field)`

1. my object class contains some properties having string and `List`
   objects.
2. iam converting theses properties into `JObject` as below

Code:

```
public static JObject ConstructFieldBody(prop1,prop2,prop3)
    {
        return new JObject
        (
            new JProperty("prop1", "value"),
            new JProperty("prop2", "value"),
            new JProperty("prop3", "value"),
        );
}
```

then i called below code from main method as follow

```
MyClass myClass= new MyClass
{
    prop1= "value",
    prop2= "value",
    prop3= "value",

};
JObject jObj =  myClass.ConstructFieldBody("valu1",valu2,"valu3");
myrepo.InsertSingle("Field", jObj);
```

inside `insertSingle()` insert code  as below

```
public void InsertSingle<T>(string table, T record) {
     var _collection = _database.GetCollection<T>(table);
     _collection.InsertOne(record);
}
```

finally i need to insert *Field* `JObject` into mongo database.

Answer (score 0):

The JObject comes from Newtonsoft.Json library, it's a type that represents a json object. It's totally different from BsonDocument which is how MongoDB represents its data.

What we'll need to do is convert it between the two, below is an easy way to do this, however you may need to alter it if you require more performance

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
await client.DropDatabaseAsync(database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName);
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");

// Get our JObject
var jObject = new JObject
(
    new JProperty("prop1", "value"),
    new JProperty("prop2", "value"),
    new JProperty("prop3", "value")
);

// Convert the JObject to a string json
var json = jObject.ToString();

// Convert the json to a Bson Document
var bsonDocument = BsonDocument.Parse(json);


await collection.InsertOneAsync(bsonDocument);
```